# how can I setup Django admin to edit multiple fields at once?

Tags: python, django, admin, models

I have a simple Django model that allows specific items in the a carousel slider to be updated.  I would like to be able to edit all the fields of these items at once in the admin.

It would be so much more convenient to edit them from the overview rather than having to click each object individually and then edit it's fields.

Here is the model from "models.py":

```py
def validate_only_three_instances(obj):
    model = obj.__class__
    # make sure of the correct quantity and allow re-saving existing objects
    if (model.objects.count() > 2 and
            model.objects.filter(id=obj.id).exists() == False):
        raise ValidationError("only 3 %ss can be created" % model.__name__)

class Slider(models.Model):
    slider_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slider_text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    slider_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=[(1, 'first'),
                                                   (2, 'middle'), (3, 'last')])

    def clean(self):
        validate_only_three_instances(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slider_title
```

this is from my "admin.py":

```py
class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # remove "add" button
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    fieldsets = [
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_title']}),
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_text']}),
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_order']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order', )
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it, you'll have to implement it yourself

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: Thank you Brandon, that's it!  If you put your response in the answer section I can mark it as solved.  By the way, I have a new problem now that I am using `list_editable`.  It is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184974/dango-admin-i-cant-list-all-of-my-fields-in-list-editable-without-causing-erro