# Cannot list all of my fields in list_editable without causing errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, admin

I'm trying to use `list_editable` to make all my fields editable on the same page. But unless I also have something in `list_display_links` I get errors.  The problems I don't have any unused fields to put there.  I am probably misunderstanding a concept somewhere.

What I have done is create a 'dummy' field in the model: `dummy = None`.  This is not only clunky and probably wrong - but it also causes the dummy field to appear in my admin.

What am I doing wrong?  I tried reading the docs but I can't find the solution to my problem.  I would like to go about this the "right way", whatever that may be.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
...

class Slider(models.Model):
    slider_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slider_text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    slider_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1, blank=True, null=True, choices=[(1, 'first'),
                                                   (2, 'middle'), (3, 'last')])
    dummy = None

    def clean(self):
        validate_only_three_instances(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slider_title

...
```

admin.py

```
...

class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # remove "add" button
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    fieldsets = [
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_title']}),
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_text']}),
        (None,  {'fields': ['slider_order']}),
    ]

    list_display = (
        'slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order', 'dummy',)
    list_display_links = ('dummy',)
    list_editable = ('slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order',)

...
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'dummy' field ?

Comment: i have to use at least one of my fields in both `list_editable` and `list display links`.  using a field from list_display is required in `list_display_links`.  i can't figure my way around those two requirements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I understand now.  For some reason the official documentation didn't click with me, however reading this did:
http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sortables.html

To sum things up:

`list_display` - is for which fields will appear in the admin page

`list_editable` - is for which fields can be edited without officially opening them up in the "edit" page.  you can basically just edit them right there on the spot in-line.  pretty awesome.

`list_display_links` - at least one item from `list_display` must serve as the link to the edit page.  this item can't also be in `list_editable` otherwise it couldn't serve as a link.  (facepalm)

This is how I ended up modifying my files:

models.py

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    ...
    link = "Edit"
    ...
```

admin.py

```
class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = (
        'slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order', 'link',)
    list_display_links = ('link',)
    list_editable = ('slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order',)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add:

```
list_display_links = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You better create a dummy column in `admin.py` as shown below instead of creating a dummy field in `models.py` to make all columns editable in Django Admin:

```py
class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    list_display = (
        'slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order', 'dummy',)
    list_display_links = ('dummy',)
    list_editable = ('slider_title', 'slider_text', 'slider_order',)

    @admin.display(description="") # Here
    def dummy(self, obj):
        return ""
```

You can see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106167/how-to-hide-the-column-assigned-to-list-display-and-list-display-links-for) expaining more details about it.