# How to hide the column assigned to "list_display" and "list_display_links" for "list_editable" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, hide, changelist

I have **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Then, I assigned `"first_name"` and `"last_name"` to [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) and [list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) to make them editable as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name") # Here
    list_editable = ("first_name", "last_name") # Here
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ERRORS: <class 'store.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E124) The value of
> 'list_editable[0]' refers to the first field in 'list_display'
> ('first_name'), which cannot be used unless 'list_display_links' is
> set.

So, I assigned `"id"` to `list_display` and [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links) as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):         # Here
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name", "id")
    list_editable = ("first_name", "last_name")
    list_display_links = ("id", ) 
                        # Here
```

Then, the error was solved and 3 columns were displayed as shown below. Now, I want to hide **the 3rd column "ID"** which I don't need:

[image]

So, how can I hide **the 3rd column "ID"**?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **the custom column "hidden"** with `hidden()` then can rename it with `@admin.display(description="")` then can assign it to `list_display` and `list_display_links` as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):           # Here
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name", "hidden")
    list_editable = ("first_name", "last_name")
    list_display_links = ("hidden", )
                          # Here
                   
    @admin.display(description="") # Here
    def hidden(self, obj):
        return ""
```

Then, you can display only 2 columns which you need as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set **list_display_links = None** in modeladmin class.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("first_name", "last_name")
    list_editable = ("first_name", "last_name")
    list_display_links = None
```